# Adding User Group to broswer role for 200+ Reports at one time

Tags: reporting-services

In Microsoft reports user, we have created some User Groups to better manage our security access from now on. Issue is that some of them need to be added to 500+ reports, and I'm not sure how to add the user group to have Browser access to all at the same time. I know how to do it per report by going to Properties -> Security -> Edit Item Security, but for 1000+ reports, that would be a monumental task. Is there any way to do it faster? Thanks!

Comment: You can set permissions at the folder level in SSRS Report Manager. That would be infinitely easier than setting permissions for each report.

Comment: Problem is, after years of adding specific security access to certain reports, more than half don't follow the parent folder security rights. We could revert it, but then we lose all the current security rights that are set on reports but not folders.